# PHP Bit shift Unexpected Results/Overflow?

Tags: php, bit-shift

In a small script I'm working on I use the follow functions:

```
function ROTR( $x, $t ){
    return( $x >> $t ) | ( $x << ( 32 - $t ) );
}

function Σ0( $x ){
    echo("SIG INPUT: " . $x . "<br>" );

    $s0 = ROTR( $x, 2 );
    $s1 = ROTR( $x, 13 );
    $s2 = ROTR( $x, 22 );

    echo( "SIGMA0 2: " . $s0 . "<br>" );
    echo( "SIGMA0 13: " . $s1 . "<br>" );
    echo( "SIGMA0 22: " . $s2 . "<br>" );

    return ( $s0 ^ $s1 ^ $s2 );
}
```

These are both defined in [this document](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.180-4.pdf) on pages 5 & 10

I apply the following and get these results:

```
Σ0( 1779033703 )
> SIG INPUT: 1779033703
> SIGMA0 2: -628983399
> SIGMA0 13: 859525199
> SIGMA0 22: 664378792
```

The input is perfectly normal, as well as the last two (`SIGMA0 13` and `SIGMA0 22`) however the `ROTR( 1779033703, 2 )` shift appears to overflow the `2^31-1` signed int limit.

The value I *am expecting* is `3665983897`, which I was able to obtain in VB.Net with:

```
' THIS SCRIPT HAS INTEGER OVERFLOW CHECKS DISABLED!
Function RotRight(x As UInt32, count As UInt32) As UInt32
    Dim t5 = x \ (2 ^ count)
    Dim t6 = x * (2 ^ (32 - count))

    Return (t5 Or t6)
End Function

Function EP0(x As UInt32) As UInt32
    Dim t7 = RotRight(x, 2)
    Dim t8 = RotRight(x, 13)
    Dim t9 = RotRight(x, 22)

    Return (t7 Xor t8 Xor t9)
End Function
```

>

```
SIG INPUT: 1779033703
SIGMA0 2: 3665983897
SIGMA0 13: 859525199
SIGMA0 22: 664378792
```

I've read that there are several ways to circumvent the overflow issue by treating the integer as a string with the gmp library, but I have not found a working method.

So far, I've tried casting the integer as a string and then using `gmp_init( string )` to convert the string into a GMP number, but the library does not appear to support bit shifting.

PS: I am using a 32bit build of PHP (I'm on Windows using XAMPP which does not support 64bit yet)

Comment: could you attach the output for each of this from your vb.net code t7 = RotRight(x, 2)
    t8 = RotRight(x, 13)
    t9 = RotRight(x, 22)

Comment: @RinsadAhmed Sorry, I forgot to include that. I've edited the question with those details. Thanks :)

Comment: what is this operator \  ?

Comment: @RinsadAhmed "Divides one operand by another and returns an integer result" https://www.tutorialspoint.com/vb.net/vb.net_operators.htm

Comment: "but the library does not appear to support bit shifting" well then you're going to need to either multiply or divide by powers of two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have a 32-bit PHP installation, and PHP does not support unsigned integers, you will need to use a library like [GMP](http://php.net/manual/en/book.gmp.php) to resolve your problem. Unfortunately GMP does not have bit-shifting arithmetic functions, however you can simulate them using division and multiplication:

```
function ROTR( $x, $t ){
    return gmp_and(gmp_or(gmp_div($x, 1 << $t), gmp_mul($x, 1 << (32 - $t))), "4294967295");
}

function Σ0( $x ){
    echo("SIG INPUT: " . $x . "\n" );

    $s0 = ROTR( $x, 2 );
    $s1 = ROTR( $x, 13 );
    $s2 = ROTR( $x, 22 );

    echo( "SIGMA0 2: " . gmp_strval($s0, 10) . "\n" );
    echo( "SIGMA0 13: " . gmp_strval($s1, 10) . "\n" );
    echo( "SIGMA0 22: " . gmp_strval($s2, 10) . "\n" );

    return ( gmp_xor($s0, gmp_xor($s1, $s2)) );
}

Σ0( 1779033703 );
```

Note that because GMP is arbitrary precision, you need to mask the output of `ROTR` to restrict it to 32 bits by bitwise `and'ing` it with `(1 << 32) - 1`.

Output:

```
SIG INPUT: 1779033703
SIGMA0 2: 3665983897
SIGMA0 13: 859525199
SIGMA0 22: 664378792
```

Here's a demo on [3v4l](https://3v4l.org/CWafR)

Comment: Perhaps I am still doing something wrong here :( I can confirm that ``$x`` is passed as an ``integer``. Both ``$g`` and ``$x`` are the same number value when ``Σ0`` is ran (the gmp_init returns an object, but the whole number portion is the same).  This time around (I've copied the exact same functions for both) I get ``SIG INPUT: 1779033703`` ``SIGMA0 2: 1910222893661452697``

Comment: 1910222893661452697 is the value you get when you use 64-bit arithmetic. The masking in `ROTR` (the outer `gmp_and` with `(1 << 32) - 1` should make that impossible. Note that the assignment to `$g` was unnecessary and I have edited it out.

Comment: I've added a demo link on `34vl.org`

Comment: I am now fairy confident it is something wrong with my PHP installation or perhaps being x86 is altering my results. Practically every online IDE I found that supports ``GMP`` (including the example you have provided) works. However, on my local x86 PHP server, I get a result as if the number has not been masked. Very strange indeed. Regardless, I very much appreciate the help!

Comment: Sorry, I'm an idiot. Because your system is 32 bits it can't represent `(1<<32)`. I've edited the code with a string value of `(1<<32)-1` i.e. `4294967295`, that should work for you. I've updated the demo link as well.